# Facebook SDK and threads (WebBrowser control)

Tags: c#, facebook

This is probably more of a general c# and simple threading question than it is a Facebook SDK question, but I may be wrong. But I could really use some help. I am reusing the sample code that comes with the SDK which includes a FacebookLoginDialog class. I am currently using it like this. In my GetMessages, GetFriendRequests, and other Get* classes, I always try/catch calls like this:

```
try
{
    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me/inbox");
}
catch (FacebookOAuthException e)
{
    FacebookSession.Login();
}
```

Here's my login method in my FacebookSession class

```
public static void Login()
{
    var fbLoginDialog = new FacebookLoginDialog(APP_ID, EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS);
    DialogResult dr = fbLoginDialog.ShowDialog();
    DisplayAppropriateMessage(fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult);
}
```

And here is the constructor in my FacebookLoginDialog class (this is where I have the problem)

```
public FacebookLoginDialog(string appId, string[] extendedPermissions, bool logout)
{
    try
    {
        var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient { AppId = appId };
        var loginParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "response_type", "token" },
            { "display", "popup" }
        };

        if (extendedPermissions != null && extendedPermissions.Length > 0)
        {
            var scope = new StringBuilder();
            scope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
            loginParameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
        }

        var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(loginParameters);

        if (logout)
        {
            var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                    { "next", loginUrl }
                                };

            System.Uri uri = 
               new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=" +
               "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&access_token=" + 
               FacebookSession._accessToken);
            this.navigateUrl = uri;
        }
        else
        {
            this.navigateUrl = loginUrl;
        }
        InitializeComponent(); // crash here... sometimes
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log error message
    }
}
```

Sorry for all the code, but now the problem. This code works fine the first time through. If I go to my facebook applications permissions page in Facebook and remove the app (that is, remove its permissions), while my desktop app here is NOT running, when I do start it up, it sees that it does not have permission and shows the login dialog. I can save the access_key and it will work just fine. But if I go to the facebook apps page and yank the permissions while my desktop app is running, then bad things happen. I get an error message about the activex control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment. I have seen many posts here that say all you have to do is put [STAThread] above your main(), and my code has that. I have also tried creating a new thread to call the FacebookLoginDialog, but not only did that not work, but since my code is really not designed to run in multiple threads, that started causing more problems.

Is there a simple solution to all this, or do I need to redesign my code so that it properly runs in multiple threads? Or should I just live with the program crashing in those few instances when someone monkeys with the facebook permissions while my app is running?

Comment: I did have one revelation. A reason that it works the first time through, but not on subsequent times might be because later times it is being done on a timer thread??? My GetMessages and GetFriendRequests etc methods are all executed on timer.elapsed calls. Could that have something to do with it?